# Flow - make it treat all imports as .js

Tags: react-native, flowtype

In my components, I create a `blah.css.js`. It's a react-native project.

I then do:

```
import styles from "blah.css";
```

The react-native module system correctly recognizes this as `"blah.css.js"`. However Flow is not. It keeps warning me "Required module not found". Screenshot below.

Is there anyway to get Flow to recongize all modules that end with `.css` as `.css.js`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to the `[options]` section of your `.flowconfig`:

```
module.name_mapper='^\(.*\).css$' -> '\1.css.js'
```

This will make Flow see any module names that finish with `.css` as finishing with `.css.js` instead.

Comment: Superb! Thank you very much Pedro!!